# Add additonal Data for each row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am displaying a GridView by building a DataTable from some other sources and use it as the Datasource of the GridView:

```
DataTable details = new DataTable();
details.Columns.Add("Name");
details.Columns.Add("Cost");
details.Columns.Add("Time");
foreach(Source s in MySource){
    DataRow detailRow = details.NewRow();
    detailRow["Id"] = 10;
    detailRow["Name"] = "test";
    detailRow["Cost"] = 10;
    detailRow["Time"] = s.GetSimplifiedTime();
    details.Rows.Add(detailRow);
}

myGrid.DataSource = details ;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

The problem is: For each row, I would need to save some additional data for some column (such as a more precise time `08/01/2023 10:23:11` for the displayed `08/01`). I would need these data in my RowSelecting Event handler.

The closest I can get is adding additional `DataKeys` columns: (However, this is not the purpose of the DataKey, and I'm using `Id` as my unique identifier already.)

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" DataKeyNames="ID, DetailedTime, FullName" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyHandler">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Process" ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-outline-success"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Due"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I wonder if there are other ways to achieve adding additional data for each row? (Even more preferable to add data for each cell, to access display name and value separately such as `Cells[0].Text` and `Cells[0].Value`).

I'm using .NET Framework 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear why some row selecting event is being used here? Why not just drop in some check box for the given row. You then let the user check box 2 rows or say 12 rows.

As for datetime? You can display the time/date in ANY format you wish, but like all date times, you can of course store the full date + time value.

So, datetime will have date + time.

So, for a hotel booking date, I can have 2 columns, one to display the date only, and another column to display the time portion of that one data column.
(Thus, both columns are from one booking database column).

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table"
    ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nights" HeaderText="Nights" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:c2}"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# string.Format("{0:c2}", Eval("MyTotal")) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMyTotal" runat="server" Text="x">
                </asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# Eval("BookingDate","{0:MMM dd}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check in" 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="90px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCheckIn" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# Eval("BookingDate","{0:HH:mm tt}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdProcess" runat="server" Text="Process Selected"
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdProcess_Click"
    />
    <asp:Label ID="lblSel" runat="server" Text="" style="margin-left:25px"  ></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

And code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        DataTable rstData;
        string strSQL = 
            @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE Active = 1
            ORDER BY HotelName";

        rstData = General.MyRst(strSQL);

        DataColumn MyCol = new DataColumn("MyTotal", typeof(decimal));
        MyCol.Expression = "[Nights] * [Price]";
        rstData.Columns.Add(MyCol);

        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        // set up the footing total.
        decimal gTotal = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in rstData.Rows)
            gTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(dr["MyTotal"]);

        Label lblTotal = (Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblMyTotal");
        lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", gTotal);

    }
```

Note the cute trick above that has an "expression" (calculation) for the one column. Few realize that expressions are allowed for columns in a data table, and they can be a combination of other columns and values as above shows.

So, with above, then have this:

[image]

So, from above:

We used a date time column with formatting. Thus, grabbing the date, the time, even just the year or whatever allows one to change the display vs the actual datetime value saved in the database.

Using a simple check box (un-bound) in the GridView, then the row selecting processing becomes rather easy, and the sample code built up both a row index list, and a database PK list of selected rows.

And note how we can add columns to the data table that are based on expressions from other columns. In this case, we created a MyTotal column based on Nights X Price.

Comment: I was using the select button field so that when one row is selected, the system will process the row and redirect the page.  However, the row selecting event does return the index of the row so it does not make the code more complex!

Comment: I did not know we can use expressions! That is actually really handy! The Datetime works nice as well!

Comment: However, I would need to store some additional data of that row that is unrelated to all other presented columns. I think retrieving them using index from the original data source does seems better!

Comment: If you are persisting or have the origional data source used to feed/create the grid view source? Then 100% agree - use the index from the existing grid row click......

Comment: It wasn't persisted, but I think persisting them doesn't harm!